# Informatica Admin console home page can't be reached

Tags: installation, console, admin, informatica

Iam able to open the admin web page just after installing informatica 9.6.1 on windows 10, but when i restart my machine (or when laptop went to sleep mode) again when checked the admin page says

```
"This site can’t be reached <hostname> refused to connect."
```

URL is `<my machine hostname>:6008/administrator/`
Is there something going wrong with the 6008 port after installation?
I used this URL for installation
https://www.edureka.co/blog/informatica-installation/)
I searched a lot on the internet but could not fix this issue.
Tried start/stop Informatica services, dint work.
 please help

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while working on windows system with Informatica 9.6.1.
I believe any of the 3 processes:  pmrepagent, pmserver  and tomcat/JAVA services
is/are not running. In simple words Informatica is not up and running.
This helped me out.
open Command prompt in Admin mode

cd C:\Informatica\9.6.1\tomcat\bin

infaservice.bat startup

for more details refer this KB article
https://network.informatica.com/thread/43165

Answer (score 1):

If you have also faced such problem while connecting to Informatica post installation then i recommend to check if you are well connected to the database which you opted while installing informatica (For eg. Oracle,sql server etc) with the same user and password which was seperately created to link the database with informatica.
If still you cannot open the Administrator homepage then you can cross check if the Informatica services are already started.You can restart the service if it is stopped and then the homepage will get open.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the service is not started. Please check the services and make sure Informatica is set to start automatically and that it's able to connect to DBMS where repository DB has been created.

Answer (score 0):

When i installed Informatica that time i was able to login to admin console. But after restart i got - "site refused to connect " error. My informatica service & oracle db serv are running. But still i could not able to login to admin console. What is did was - i login to the schema what i used while installing informatica server through dbeaver tool. On my astonishment, after that im now able to connect admin console.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found another error that caused this kind of issue.
Check in your system where information is installed and search for "Catalina.out"
See the error:

```
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: [localhost-startStop-2] The web application [/csm] appears to have started a thread named [phoneHomeScheduler] but has failed to stop it. 
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

You need to restart the system and re-process the services.